# How to access SSL in KeyVault from ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

**Duplicate Question?**

*I don't believe it is. As stated, this is working using my user from a local deployment and all (as I understand it) permissions have been granted to the Service Principal and the test user that also fails locally.*

I have an ARM template that provisions and deploys a web app, part of that is to apply a certificate binding to the webapp. That part of the template looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "api",
  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(parameters('servicePlanGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('servicePlanName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('certificateName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "keyVaultId": "[parameters('keyVaultId')]",
        "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('keyVaultSecretName')]"
      }
    }
   ]
  }
```

When I run this locally from my PC it works fine, when I run it from the VSTS the deployment fails, and look like this:

[image]

Where the error is:

```
"operationName": {
    "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Web/certificates/write",
    "value": "Microsoft.Web/certificates/write"
},
"properties": {
    "statusCode": "Unauthorized",
    "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"\"}}"
}
```

The SSL certificate and the KeyVault both have permissions added for the Service Principal that VSTS runs under for this release.

The Release Principal user has `Read,List` for keys and secrets in the KeyVault and is a `Contributor` in the subscription. My account which works locally is `co-admin`.

Any ideas on what permissions need to be added?

**Update**

I added another user `testuser` which has the same rights as the Service Principal and it now fails locally. I guess it will be some trial and error to add permissions and see what works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with KeyVault reference in ARM template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134416/issue-with-keyvault-reference-in-arm-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a duplicate question - as mentioned it was pointing to strange permission issue across accounts, even though the permissions were set. It turns out that for some reason the co-admin will work despite the below issue - a potential bug in the ARM/permission infrastructure, maybe?

This works for co-admin user but not anyone else.

[image]

Whereas this works for a lesser privileged user/principal.

[image]

Note the schema version change. The original schema of `2014-04-01` doesn't actually include anything about `Microsoft.Web/Certificates` whereas the updated schema `2015-08-01` does include this information.

Local testing using the `testuser` with same privileges as the VSTS service principal is working fine with this change.

Side Note for anyone else trying to achieve SSL bindings:

The location of resources in my example is all the same. I suspect if the vault is in a different location, then its resource group may also need to be specified for this to work the same - I haven't tested that theory though.