# Deploy Web App certificate from Azure Keyvault and create SSL binding

Tags: azure, templates, web-applications, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to figure out to fix the below problem while deploying Azure RM template.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:54:31 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/certificates 'redacted' failed with message '{   "Code": "BadRequest",   "Message": "The service does not have access to '/subscriptions/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/redacted' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have  granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation.",   "Target": null,   "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The service does not have access to  '/subscriptions/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/redacted' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have  granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "59716",
        "MessageTemplate": "The service does not have access to '{0}' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform  the request operation.",
        "Parameters": [          "/subscriptions/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/redacted"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The service does not have access to  '/subscriptions/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/redacted' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have  granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation."
      }
    }   ],   "Innererror": null }' At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name redacted -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:54:31 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name redacted -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:54:31 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name redacted -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I have created a web app and want to bind an SSL certificate stored as a secret from Azure Keyvault. At first, I have created a self-signed certificate and uploaded it to keyvault as a 'secret'. From the Azure Active Directory, I have created a web app and used the application ID to grant access to key vault.

Following deployment template was used:

[Azure RM template for deploying web app certificate from keyvault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-certificate-from-key-vault)

Comment: Have you followed that full steps from that Azure RM template link you provided? or just deploy the templates?

Comment: I have followed complete steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Resource Provider has no permission to access the Key Vault.

> By default, 'Microsoft.Azure.WebSites' Resource Provider (RP) doesn't
>   have access to the Key Vault specified in the template hence you need
>   to authorize it by executing the following PowerShell commands before
>   [deploying the template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-certificate-from-key-vault).

The RP requires read access to KeyVault. ‘abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd’ is the RP service principal name and it remains same for all Azure subscriptions.

`Login-AzureRmAccount 
 Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
 Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName 
 abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134416/issue-with-keyvault-reference-in-arm-template) is a similar case.

Comment: I have created a App service and registered in Active Directory. Then, ran the above commands to login to azure subscription, set the subscription (where keyvault exists). I got the Application ID of the registered app service and then set access policy on the key vault. Then, ran the template

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ssl -ResourceGroupName ssl-rg -TemplateFile C:\Template\azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\Template\azuredeploy.parameters.json`

Comment: I mean the " abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd " is the global uniqueness of the application ID of "Microsoft.Azure.WebSites". You should use this ID in the commands.

Comment: Won't using " abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd " mean that any web app (not just mine) will have access to the keyvault?

Comment: @user648931, no, the "abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd" just represent the service principal of 'Microsoft.Azure.WebSites' Resource Provider (RP). It happens the RP need access the Key Vault.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I was using wrong application ID. The following step is the right one

Run the following command and replace application ID from the output
`Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft.Azure.WebSites"`

Mostly likely application ID would still be the same.

`Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName 
 abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get`

I created an AppService and replaced `abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd` with application ID of my AppService which was wrong.

Comment: `-SearchString` does not return any results for me. Searching for `-ServicePrincipleName` however, returns the service principle with ID `abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd`, as @doubledecker mentioned. `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName "Microsoft.Azure.WebSites"`

Answer (score 1):

not a direct answer but will surely help

```
#Microsoft Azure App Service
#Name: Microsoft Azure WebSites    
$AppServicePrincipalId = "abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd"
$KeyVaultSecretsUserRoleId = "4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6"
$AppServicePrincipalObjectId = az ad sp show --id $AppServicePrincipalId --query objectId
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id $AppServicePrincipalObjectId --role $KeyVaultSecretsUserRoleId --scope $keyVaultScope --subscription $subscriptionName --assignee-principal-type "ServicePrincipal"


az webapp config hostname add --webapp-name $webAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --hostname $hostname
$sslResult = (az webapp config ssl import --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $webAppName --key-vault $keyVaultName --key-vault-certificate-name $certificateName | convertfrom-json)
az webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint $sslResult.thumbprint --ssl-type SNI --name $webAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to add the policies through the `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy`  command due to an error in the console.

I was however able to resolve the issue through the Azure Web Interface by opening the KeyVault Access Control(IAM) and adding `Key Vault Reader` and `Key Vault Secrets User` roles to `Microsoft.Azure.Websites`

[image]